# Switch : Enum Switch issue : Not member of a int

Tags: swift, enums

I am writing my first project in Swift(I have been doing ObjectiveC for years) and for some reason, I cant work out why my enum and Switch are not working togetber

```
enum ContactViewMode : Int
    {
        case ViewModeFavourite = 0
        case ViewModeRecent = 1
        case ViewModeContacts = 2
    }
```

Property

```
 @IBInspectable var contactViewMode : Int!
```

Switch

```
switch contactViewMode {
            case ContactViewMode.ViewModeFavourite:
                contacts = DBManager.getFavouriteContacts() as [ContactEntity]
            case ContactViewMode.ViewModeRecent:
                contacts = DBManager.getFavouriteContacts() as [ContactEntity]
            default:
                contacts = DBManager.getAllContacts() as [ContactEntity]
        }
```

The error I get is 
**Enum case 'ViewModeFavourite' is not a member of type 'Int!'**

So I changed it to this as it is not a Int! (I need Int! for Storyboard)

```
var contactMode:Int = contactViewMode

        switch contactMode {
            case .ViewModeFavourite:
                contacts = DBManager.getFavouriteContacts() as [ContactEntity]
            case .ViewModeRecent:
                contacts = DBManager.getFavouriteContacts() as [ContactEntity]
            default:
                contacts = DBManager.getAllContacts() as [ContactEntity]
        }
```

Then I get
 **Enum case pattern cannot match values of the non-enum type 'Int'**

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You have to declare `contactViewMode` as `ContactViewMode` and not `Int`.

If you really want it to be `Int`, then you have to change the cases in your switch, by comparing the variable to the `rawValue` property of the enum cases:

```
switch contactViewMode {
case ContactViewMode.ViewModeFavourite.rawValue:
    contacts = DBManager.getFavouriteContacts() as [ContactEntity]
case ContactViewMode.ViewModeRecent.rawValue:
    contacts = DBManager.getFavouriteContacts() as [ContactEntity]
default:
    contacts = DBManager.getAllContacts() as [ContactEntity]
}
```

but unless you have a good reason for that, I wouldn't recommend

Answer (score 27):

The other answers fail to take advantage of Swift’s strong typing. Note that they all have a `default` case in their `switch`. Swift knows at compile time, however, whether you have covered all cases of an `enum` or not, thus rendering the `default` case unnecessary.

This is a useful feature of the language. Imagine you add an extra `case` to your `enum` at a later point. The compiler will complain and point you to all the `switch`es that are not considering that particular `case`.

How can we take advantage of Swift’s strong typing, then?

First, let’s fix the naming of your enumeration. As I assume you are nesting it inside a `ContactView` class (and, unlike in Objective-C, it should really be *inside* it), you can name the `enum` simply `Mode`. No need to mention `ViewMode`s in the cases, either. This way you get a cleaner, more idiomatic type.

```
enum Mode: Int {
    case favourite
    case recent
    case contacts
}
```

What we need to do is to perform the `switch` on a `Mode`, not on an `Int`. Your `Mode` is `RawRepresentable`, and as such you can do:

```
guard let m = Mode(rawValue: contactViewMode) else { /* handle the situation */ }
switch m {
    case .favourite: /* handle case */
    case .recent: /* handle case */
    case .contacts: /* handle case */
}
```

That’s all there is to it—instead of switching on the `rawValue`, get the proper `Mode` first and then switch on it.

Comment: Even the .rawValue is most people's choice, I believe this answer is the most elegant way to coding. Imagine this: there are a hundred items in the enum type, the .rawValue way is really ugly.

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me:

I have an enum like this:

```
enum Proximity{
  case Unknown
  case Immediate
  case Near
  case Far
}
```

Then a switch that looks like this:

```
switch b.proximity as Proximity {
    case Proximity.Immediate:
         if b.rssi == -30 && b.accuracy == 0.2345{
             closestBeacon = b
         }
    case Proximity.Near:
         return
    case Proximity.Far:
         return
    default:
         return
 }
```

Im looping through an array of "b" objects that have a proximity property.

Comment: I kinda like this answer.

Comment: I still don't understand however, why do we need to do `b.proximity as Proximity`.. shouldn't the compiler already know that `b.proximity` is of type `Proximity`?

Answer (score 4):

Enumerations are types. Just because you make clear that the single enum values can be cast to `Int` doesn't make it valid to declare `contactViewMode` an `Int!`. The types simply don't match.

So either declare `contactViewMode` as `ContactViewMode`, use your first `switch` statement and cast to `Int!` when you actually need it for the storyboard, or use the second `switch`, but don't use `.ViewModeFacourite` et al, but the corresponding `Int` value.

```
var contactMode:Int = contactViewMode

    switch contactMode {
        case ContactViewMode.ViewModeFavourite.rawValue:
            contacts = DBManager.getFavouriteContacts() as [ContactEntity]
        case ContactViewMode..ViewModeRecent.rawValue:
            contacts = DBManager.getFavouriteContacts() as [ContactEntity]
        default:
            contacts = DBManager.getAllContacts() as [ContactEntity]
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot directly match `Int` with `enum`. Instead, you have to convert `ContactViewMode` to `Int` with `.rawValue` property, OR convert `Int` to `ContactViewMode` with `init(rawValue:)` initializer.

The latter example:

```
switch ContactViewMode(rawValue: contactViewMode) {
case .Some(.ViewModeFavourite):
    contacts = DBManager.getFavouriteContacts() as [ContactEntity]
case .Some(.ViewModeRecent):
    contacts = DBManager.getFavouriteContacts() as [ContactEntity]
default:
    contacts = DBManager.getAllContacts() as [ContactEntity]
}
```

because `ContactViewMode(rawValue:)` returns Optionals, we need `.Some()`.

Comment: What exactly does the `.Some` do? Do you have a link to the docs?

Comment: @fabian789 It's called ["Enumeration Case Pattern"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/Patterns.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH36-XID_1012). Because [`Optional`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Types.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH31-XID_1126) is just a `enum` (`.None` or `.Some(T)`), we can match against it with that patterns.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use contactViewMode and create a new var of type  `ContactViewMode` in case value of `contactViewMode` is coming from somewhere else and it has to be `int`.

```
let contactMode :ContactViewMode = ContactViewMode(rawValue: contactViewMode)!
```

Now you can easily use switch as shown below:

```
switch contactMode {
            case .ViewModeFavourite:
                contacts = DBManager.getFavouriteContacts() as [ContactEntity]
            case .ViewModeRecent:
                contacts = DBManager.getFavouriteContacts() as [ContactEntity]
            default:
                contacts = DBManager.getAllContacts() as [ContactEntity]
        }
```